# Angular gridster moving issue

Tags: angularjs, gridster

I'm trying to create an example using angular gridster but I'm not able to reach my goal.  All I want to do is that if I move item A between item B and item C, item C will be pushed to the right, item B will be pushed to the left, and item A will take the place of item B.

What happens is that I can only move an item to an empty place.
Here are the options that I'm using:

```
$scope.gridsterOptions = {
    columns: 12,
    maxRows: 1,
    pushing: false,
    floating: false,
    resizable: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    draggable: {
        enabled: true, // whether dragging items is supported
    }
};
```

Can anybody fix that?
Here is the sample code on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bKgu2B?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `pushing: false,` add this new line:

```
swapping: true,
```

This should fix it.